# How to parse using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Giving

```
<div class="alert_right">
<p>welcome!<script>setTimeout("window.location.href ='index.php';", 1000);</script></p></div>
```

How to get the **welcome!**  text using Jsoup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `HTML` is in a `String`, you can use the following code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HTML);
Elements div =  doc.select(".alert_right > p:nth-child(1)");
String s = div.text();
```

Now `s` is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Following is the another way to get **welcome!**  text.

```
StringBuffer myHTML = new StringBuffer();
myHTML.append("<div class=\"alert_right\"><p>welcome!" +
            "<script>setTimeout(\"window.location.href =\'index.php\';\", 1000);</script>" +
            "</p></div>");
Document myDoc = Jsoup.parse(myHTML.toString());
//get first child of div
String result = myDoc.select("div.alert_right").get(0).text();
System.out.println(result);
```